# Обновил приложение в play market. В Play Store у приложения отображается новая версия, а скачивается старая

Tags: android, flutter, playmarket, обновление-приложений

1. Написал свое первое приложение на Flutter, выложил в AppStore и в Play Market. На iOS все работает, а на Андройде зависало при загрузке.
2. Стал разбираться в чем дело. Пока разбирался, проверил одну гипотезу. Проверял ее на внутреннем тестировании. Т.е. создал новую сборку app-release.aab и загрузил в плей маркет.
3. Гипотеза сработала.
4. Снова создал новую версию, и выложил ее в плей маркете, подождал, пока ее проверят. Но после загрузки на телефон открывается версия, которую проверял в гипотезе (шаг 2)
5. После этого загружал в плей маркет еще несколько версий, и во внутреннее тестирование и в закрытое тестирование, но почему-то ставиться версия приложения описанная в шаге 2.

С компьютера все нормально запускается и работает.

Буду благодарен за любую помощь и подсказку.

Comment: попробуйте удалить себя из внутреннего тестирования, раньше была кнопка "удалить тестировщиков", т.е. вообще завершить внутреннее тестирование.

Comment: Спасибо! Вопрос снят. Все у меня обновлялось. Проблема в моей невнимательности.